# PHP keep checkbox ticked in checkbox array after submit error

Tags: php, arrays, post, checkbox, checked

I have looked through stackoverflow and can't seem to find exactly what i am looking .I am trying to figure this out and have spent a few hours on it so far.

I have database results being outputted and producing boxes with text in via a foreach and in the foreach statement there is the following code to build an array for print_select. I need the checkbox selections to remain if there are errors with my form and someone then goes back to the intial page where the checkboxes are (I have all the form and errors part done).

This is the html I have:

```
<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"print_select[]\" value=\"{$value['id']}\">
```

The {$value['id']} represents numeric values and each one is different.

Now had this been a simple name="something" I could have just set it to selected after the page reloaded with some php but this uses an array which makes it slightly tricky for me.

Has anyone been able to keep checkbox selections after post when its using an array? I am probably missing something really simple but thought it was worth asking here aswell.

Comment: you would echo "checked" in the html of the chekbox based on the content of the POST\GET array

Comment: Yeah I thought the same but each html checkbox output is in a foreach so I am finding it hard to write code which doesn't make them all checked.

Comment: if you post the foreach loop and the array, i will take a look

Comment: Unfortunently the code is too big just to post. Basically I have a foreach looping from an array from a database and then in each iteration there is the html checkbox with name="print_select[]" then if whatever the user selects that runs a script which emails certain stuff thats all working , its just keeping them checked if there is an error thats the issue and the foreach isn't helping because whatever i try it checks them all.

Comment: you would check against the post\get array which would contain the ones checked.